# Are there any NTS index maps showing the most recent update?

Tags: cartography, topography, canada

For the Canadian National Topographic System, are there any index maps available that do not only show map numbers throughout the country, but also the most recently available update for each map?

As a bonus, is there any publicly available list showing the plan for updates for the next several years, for NTS maps?

I could not find either on the [NTS website](http://www.nrcan.gc.ca/earth-sciences/geography/topographic-information/maps/9763).